# Displaying output message only on success within NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, node-modules, dom-events

```
var abc = require("expect-telnet");

abc("linux123:2031",
console.log("Telnet working"),
function(err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
});
```

It is displaying the message `Telnet working` in all scenarios.
I want it to be displayed only when we have successful telnet connection.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code you don't have to authenticate your telnet since I don't see you sending a username or password.  If that's not the case you'll need to send your authentication.

You'll want to change it to something like the code shown below.
Remove the lines for authentication if not needed.

```
var abc = require("expect-telnet");

abc("linux123:2031", [
  {expect: "Username", send: "username\r"},
  {expect: "Password", send: "password\r"},
  {expect: "#"       , send: "command\r" },
  {expect: "#"       , out: function(output) {
    console.log("telnet working");
  }, send: "status\r"}
], function(err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
});
```

**Give this a try when no authentication is needed:**
This code waits for telnet to respond with the '#' character once connected. Once it sees that, you should get the console.log info.

I hope this helps.

```
var abc = require("expect-telnet");

abc("linux123:2031", [
  {expect: "#"       , out: function(output) {
    console.log("telnet working");
  }, send: "status\r"}
], function(err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I am not using `username` for telnet. It is not printing `telnet working` when successful. When i manually do `telnet linux123 2013` then I see a blank screen but no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
var abc = require("expect-telnet");

abc("linux123:2031",function(err,data) {
  if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }else {
        console.log("Telnet working")
    }
});
```